# Graph API posting jobs and retrieving applications through a separate ATS

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I have gone in details through the [Jobs XML documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/jobs-xml).
The steps that I completed are :

1. Creating a recruitment manager to post and retrieve jobs.
2. Created a url for Facebook to crawl job xml data referring [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/jobs-xml/specification).

My question refers to `application-callback-url` section in the xml which specifies to configure an endpoint to receive applications received from facebook in raw json data.

**Question**

1. I don't want to receive applications from Facebook but rather want to redirect the user to a particular ATS where the applicant can proceed with their application. It should be `Apply on Website` and not just `Apply` when I post jobs. This is [where](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/jobs-xml/how-to#application-callback-payload) all the necessary information needs to be present but I couldn't find anything relevant to my use case.
2. There are 2 endpoints `/me/jobs` and `/me/job_feeds`. I am not understanding the difference between the 2 and which one should I be using as per my use case?

Comment: @CBroe But in Facebook Jobs section you would find job ads which has `Apply on Website` option. On clicking it, you'd be redirected to that particular ATS.

Comment: Possible that this is something you can only specify when creating jobs manually. In the specification for the XML feed, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/jobs-xml/specification, I don’t find any mention of the ability to set a custom application URL.